# SCCM R3 package failure

Tags: sccm

Im having issues with a few packages failing in SCCM R3 and im wondering the folllowing.

It says it should try to reinstall if it failed the first time, what are the rules that govorn this ( IE how long before it tries, how many times and so on).

Is there realy no "failure" handeling? IE if the package fails run the following program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says it should try to reinstall if it failed the first time, what are the rules that govorn this ( IE how long before it tries, how many times and so on).

Within the "Software Distribution" component of SCCM, nearly everything you create is uniquely identified by clients. This is true of packages, advertisements, and any mandatory assignments. Selecting "Rerun if failed previous attempt" when setting up a mandatory advertisement means that clients will try running the program if all of the following are true:

- The client has not already run this particular assignment.
- Either the program has never been run before or it indicated failure last time it ran.

I don't think modifying a program will cause clients to rerun it.

> Is there realy no "failure" handeling? IE if the package fails run the following program?

SCCM relies on the returned status code of any programs that run. Many packages return status codes unrecognized by SCCM. Consider wrapping your executable in a batch or powershell script, and controlling success/failure reporting with the ERRORLEVEL environment variable.

Comment: +1 SCCM will only rerun the failed program at the next assigned time. If it was only assigned for a single time, then it wont rerun. Big +1 for wrapping odd installers in a batch file or similar to handle any strange return codes. Be cognisant of what you are installing and how it installs.

Comment: It was the assigned time that aws screwing me up alot.